# Adding fade transition effect and automatic image change

Tags: javascript, slideshow, transition, fade

Hi I'm new to JavaScript and having difficulty creating the solution for this code I am developing.
I need to add a fade transition effect to my slideshow (an image changing into another one). The images should change automatically in addition to the already existing buttons. Here is the full code:
EDIT: I (@albert) put the code into the snippets and just grabbed the first two images I came across...

```js
    var slideIndex = 1;
    showDivs(slideIndex);
    function plusDivs(n) {
    showDivs(slideIndex += n);
    }

    function currentDiv(n) {
    showDivs(slideIndex = n);
    }
    function showDivs(n) {
    var i;
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("slides");
    var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("active");
    if (n > x.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
    if (n < 1) {slideIndex = x.length}
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = "none";  
    }
    for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" white", "");
    }
    x[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
    dots[slideIndex-1].className += " white";
    }
```

```css
    .circle{
     height:9px;
     width:9px;
     padding:0;
     background-color:#000;
     }
    .container{
             position:relative;
               max-width:800px;
               max-height:350px;
               overflow:hidden;
    }
    .centered{
             text-align:center;
               margin-bottom:16px;
               font-size:18px;
               color:white;   
           position:absolute;
               left:0;
               bottom:0;               
     }
    .left-arrow{
             float:left;
               padding-left:16px;
               cursor:pointer
     }
    .right-arrow{
             float:right;
               padding-right:16px;
               cursor:pointer
    }
    .arrow:hover{
               color:#b4aa50;
    }
    .arrow{
            -webkit-transition:background-color .3s,color .15s,box-shadow 
    .3s,opacity 0.3s;
             transition:background-color .3s,color .15s,box-shadow 
    .3s,opacity   0.3s;
    }
    .circle-b{
               border:1px solid #fff;
             background-color:transparent;
                   -webkit-transition:background-color .3s,color .15s,box-shadow 
    .3s,opacity 0.3s;
                   transition:background-color .3s,color .15s,box-shadow 
    .3s,opacity 0.3s;
    }
    .circle-b:hover{
               color:#000;
               background-color:#fff;                  
    }

    .white{
               color:#000;background-color:#fff}
    }
```

```html
    <div class="container">
  
    <img class="slides" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/b9ukx.png" style="width:100%">
    <img class="slides" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/wx8jF.png" style="width:100%">
    
      <div class="centered" style="width:100%">
            <div class="left-arrow arrow" onclick="plusDivs(-1)">&#10094</div>
            <div class="right-arrow arrow" onclick="plusDivs(1)">&#10095</div>
            <span class="circle active circle-b " onclick="currentDiv(1)"> </span>
            <span class="circle active circle-b " onclick="currentDiv(2)"> </span>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: this is possible in pure css; would you care for that solution, or does this require javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote this from scratch and made a fiddle for you: https://jsfiddle.net/bartlomiej/kdg581sL/ (You need to set `load type` to `no wrap - in <body>` in javascript settings to see it working)

I hope that's exactly what you wanted to achieve.

Firstly I set initial value of `slideIndex` to `0`.

```
var slideIndex = 0;
```

And I save array of images elements to `slides` variable and set length of that array to `length`.

```
var slides = document.getElementById('slides').children
var length = slides.length
```

Next line set class `active` to image element defined in `stateIndex`.

```
setActiveSlide(slideIndex);
```

Then we need three functions:

`showPrevSlide()` which set class `active` to previous slide ONLY if the slide isn't first.

```
function showPrevSlide() {
  if (slideIndex - 1 != -1) {
    slideIndex -= 1;
  }

  setActiveSlide(slideIndex);
}
```

`showNextSlide()` which set class `active` to next slide ONLY if slide isn't the last one.

```
function showNextSlide() {
  if (slideIndex + 1 < length) {
    slideIndex += 1;
  }

  setActiveSlide(slideIndex);
}
```

And finally `setActiveSlide()` which iterate over all images elements and add `active` class to image element defined in `index`.

```
function setActiveSlide(index) {
  for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    if (index == i) {
      slides[i].className += ' active';
    } else {
      slides[i].className = 'slide';
    }
  }
}
```

To reach fade transition effect on slides you should use `transition` and `opacity` CSS properties. You also need to set `position` to `absolute` so the images will be placed one on another.

```
.slide {
 position: absolute;
 opacity: 0;
 transition: 1s;
}
```

And `active` class styles.

```
.slide.active {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

I hope my answer helped you.

EDIT: If you want to change slides in infinite way you have to edit `showPrevSlide()` and `showNextSlide()` a bit.

```
function showPrevSlide() {
  if (slideIndex - 1 == -1) { 
    slideIndex = length - 1; 
  } else {
    slideIndex -= 1;
  }

  setActiveSlide(slideIndex);
}

function showNextSlide() {
  if (slideIndex + 1 < length) {
    slideIndex += 1;
  } else {
    slideIndex = 0;
  }

  setActiveSlide(slideIndex);
}
```

And if you want images to change automatically just use `setInterval`. For example: `setInterval(function() { showNextSlide() }, 1000);` where `1000` is time in ms.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I would just need an automatic image change to this code. Is it possible?

Comment: I would also need an "infinite" possibility to change images; (If I click on the right arrow when the last image is active, the code restarts from the first one, and same for the left arrow)

Comment: I edited my answer and implemented features which you want.

Comment: Thank you so much!